# Trying to change WL tokens

Tags: nft

My contract has a change state function but when called its reverting error.

"type": "Error",
"value": "execution reverted: only for sale contract\n{\n  "originalError": {\n    "code": 3,\n    "data": "0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000166f6e6c7920666f7220...",

this is the contract:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x38d3A36417115668444B1eA132637d85C6074058#readContract

Answer (score 0):

That message only appears in a modifier

```
modifier onlySaleContract()
{
    require(msg.sender == saleContractAddress, "only for sale contract");
    _;
}
```

The modifier is only used by

```
function setRoyaltyKindForTokenBatch(
    uint256 _fromId,
    uint256 _toId,
    uint256 _kind) external override onlySaleContract
{
    ...
}
```

So only the `saleContractAddress` (at `0x0AFB3bcDd8b40EDb8D98F2b5f73134DAf1cc108d`) can call that function.